# SQL For each statement

Tags: mysql

I am working on some SQL homework and could someone explain to me how to get this question done.

2. Display the average raw scores of team ‘Dolphins (1 point)

Here is an image of the data structure.

[image: DataStructure]

I need to make a query that returns the average raw score of 4 players.
However, when I try executing the code below it just returns one average.

```
/* Question 2 */
SELECT AVG(RawScore)
FROM Bowler_Scores
WHERE BowlerID IN
(
SELECT BowlerID
FROM Bowlers
WHERE TeamID =
(
SELECT TeamID
FROM Teams
WHERE TeamName = "Dolphins"));
```

In bowler scores each bowler id can have multiple scores.
For instance it may have the records - (43,101) (50,301) and (43,106).

I don't know how to write and sql statement that will get the average raw score for each player on that team out of all of there individual raw scores in the bowler scores table.

Comment: That's a really bad way to go about it, and it doesn't really address the problem from the OP. Also, please don't post code in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need the average individual scores for each member of the Dolphins Team you can use this:

```
Select Teams.TeamName, Bowlers.BowlerID, avg(Rawscore)
from   Bowlers
inner join Teams
on    Bowlers.TeamId = Teams.TeamID
inner join  Bowler_Scores
on    Bowlers.BowlerID = Bowler_Scores.BowlerID
where  teams.teamname = 'Dolphins'
group by TeamName, BowlerID
```

If you just need one average score for the team then just remove the BowlerID from the SELECT and GROUP BY lines.

Comment: it says ERROR 1052 Column BowlerID in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Add the table names to the columns (see the on clause of the join for examples)

Comment: You would also need to add a where clause to limit the results to the one desired team name.

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Because BowlerID is in both the Bowlers Table and the Bowlers_Score table you have to add the table name before the field so SQL knows which one to use.

Comment: Check the edited Select statement in the Answer above.  The table names were added to the TeamName and BowlerID selects.

Comment: Thank you so much. I guess i wasn't full understanding the concepts of group by and implementing inner joins instead of wheres. This was extremely helpful.

Comment: Where would I insert the where clause

Comment: Above the GROUP BY.

Comment: I ment where. I tried adding it in the first inner join but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Why does it go under the Bowler scores inner join and not the teams inner join?

Comment: Think of it in sections: SELECT  JOINS  WHERE  GROUP BY  ORDER BY  This will serve you for most of your SQL statements.